# not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver, SQLite only supports TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY cursors

Tags: java, mysql, database, sqlite, jdbc

I need to update the the price of every track in the database.
I am trying to do this by updating the the result set.When I try it without the ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, I get the error that this function is not implemented by the JDBC driver and when I include it I get an error that SQLite supports  TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY cursors.

```
private static void update_track_price_batch() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Enter the % value between 100 and -100");
        Scanner percentage_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        float percentage = percentage_input.nextFloat();
        float change = 100 + percentage ;
        Connection myConn = null;
        try
        {

        myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:chinook.db");
        myst = myConn.prepareStatement("select * from Track", ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        ResultSet myres = myst.executeQuery();

        while (myres.next())
        {
            float f = myres.getFloat("UnitPrice");
            int row_id = myres.getInt("TrackId");
            myres.updateFloat("UnitPrice", f*change);
            myres.updateRow();
        }
```

Comment: How about using ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY?

Comment: then i get the error- SQLite only supports CONCUR_READ_ONLY cursors :/

Comment: How about using ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY _and_ ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY? :)

Comment: If its read only, how will i update it?
And, it shows the earlier again-  function is not implemented by the JDBC driver.

Comment: Issuing update statements. `"update table_x set column=something..."`

Comment: @zed Eighter use multiple statements, or consider using another driver. SQLite isn't the only driver that works with file database instead of a remote database (like MySQL). For example DerbySQL is an alternative to SQLite.